# Wrong behavior of MS Access Left Join

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I'm encountering a weird behaviour on MS Access 365 (version 1908) when performing a left join between a table and a subquery on a fixed value colum.

Suppose we have 2 tables:

TableA

```
ID  FIELD1  CATEG
1   A       CATEG_POS
2   B       CATEG_NEG
3   C       CATEG_POS
4   D       CATEG_NEG
5   E       CATEG_NEG
```

And TableB

```
FIELD1  FIELD2
C       100
D       -23
E       -40
F       78
G       20
H       50
```

And let's suppose that I want all records from table A and left join TableB on FIELD1 and only on negative values of FIELD2.

I would write the following query that gives me the desired result:

```
SELECT *
FROM
        TableA a
LEFT JOIN
        (
                SELECT
                        FIELD1,
                        Iif(FIELD2>0, "CATEG_POS", "CATEG_NEG") AS CATEG
                FROM
                        TableB 
                WHERE FIELD2<0        
                        ) b
ON
        b.FIELD1 = a.FIELD1
AND     b.CATEG  = a.CATEG
```

Resulting in

```
ID  a.FIELD1    a.CATEG     b.FIELD1    b.CATEG
1   A           CATEG_POS               CATEG_NEG
2   B           CATEG_NEG               CATEG_NEG
3   C           CATEG_POS               CATEG_NEG
4   D           CATEG_NEG   D           CATEG_NEG
5   E           CATEG_NEG   E           CATEG_NEG
```

Since Access doesn't support join conditions like

> ```
> ON
>         b.FIELD1 = a.FIELD1
> AND     b.CATEG  = a.CATEG
> AND     b.CATEG  = "CATEG_NEG" <----- not supported
> ```

I'm forced to put the negative filter inside the where condition of the subquery.

---

EDIT: thanks to the comments to this post, I discovered that this join condition is supported but needs to be correctly enclosed in brackets. Anyway this leads to an incorrect result because it filters the result set on records that have CATEG = "CATEG_NEG".

---

Everything is ok until here.
Now, since I'm filtering the subquery just on negative values, I know that the calculated CATEG column would always evaluate to CATEG_NEG, so I tried to change the query using a fixed value of CATEG in the subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM
        TableA a
LEFT JOIN
        (
                SELECT
                        FIELD1,
                        "CATEG_NEG" AS CATEG
                FROM
                        TableB 
                WHERE FIELD2<0        
                        ) b
ON
        b.FIELD1 = a.FIELD1
AND     b.CATEG  = a.CATEG
```

That gives this output:

```
ID  a.FIELD1    a.CATEG     b.FIELD1    b.CATEG
2   B           CATEG_NEG               CATEG_NEG
4   D           CATEG_NEG   D           CATEG_NEG
5   E           CATEG_NEG   E           CATEG_NEG
```

That is not a left join result because not all records from first join operand are returned.
Why?
Is this a known Access issue?

Please let me know what I am doing wrong or not understanding.

I know I could simply remove the join condition b.CATEG  = a.CATEG but in my actual code I have a sightly different situation where I cannot do this.
I've uploaded a small Excel example here: http://www.filedropper.com/leftjointest

Thanks to everyone in advance.

Edit: here is the code to generate the 2 tables with the contained sample data.

```
CREATE TABLE TableA (ID NUMBER, FIELD1 CHAR, CATEG CHAR);
CREATE TABLE TableB (FIELD1 CHAR, FIELD2 NUMBER);
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES (1, "A", "CATEG_POS");
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES (2, "B", "CATEG_NEG");
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES (3, "C", "CATEG_POS");
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES (4, "D", "CATEG_NEG");
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES (5, "E", "CATEG_NEG");
INSERT INTO TableB VALUES ("C", 100);
INSERT INTO TableB VALUES ("D", -23);
INSERT INTO TableB VALUES ("E", -40);
INSERT INTO TableB VALUES ("F", 78);
INSERT INTO TableB VALUES ("G", 20);
INSERT INTO TableB VALUES ("H", 50);
```

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code in table format. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, **chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Put what is needed in your post, not just at a link. Insert links/images via site edit functions.

Comment: Thanks @philipxy, I replaced images with text. All code examples are shown, both the working one and the not working one. Please specify what's missing, thanks.

Comment: @philipxy I just added input as code. Runnable code was already provided and I just assured that it can be copied and pasted in Access sql window to be run. The example is quite simple and minimal, I don't think anything else is needed, just the will to help ;) That join condition is not supported, Access returns an error message saying "JOIN operation not supported" and the join condition "b.CATEG  ='CATEG_NEG' "is highlighted, both when using single or double quotes. By the way, I also uploaded and shared a working Access db with the provided example.

Comment: Access has egregious bugs. [Behaviour like your question.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/fc965690-34d7-4f81-8c6a-d0e200d6f01e/left-join-not-returning-any-rows-when-the-join-field-is-a-constant?forum=accessdev) Re "not supported", that may be as simple as parentheses around on conditions. Your .accdb is corrupt for me & sites die, this is why everything necessary should be text in the post. PS I don't know how people think "cut & paste & run" an "example" doesn't include data. PS Tabular initialization code makes non-code tables redundant & error-prone. Good luck.

Comment: @philipxy unfortunately, even when bracketing the join condition, when this is on a constant value, Access will filter the result set on that value, that is to me a wrong left join behavior, just as the one described on your linked post. I just edited the initial post accordingly. About your claim on the corrupted .accdb on the provided link, I just downloaded it and it works ok to me. Make sure you donwloaded the right file.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure i understand you well, but... If you want to get only negative values from `TableB`, you have to add this condition into `LEFT JOIN` statement:

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM TableA AS a LEFT JOIN TableB AS b ON a.Field1 = b.Field1 AND b.Field2<0;
```

Result:

```
ID  a.FIELD1    CATEG       b.FIELD1    FIELD2
1   A           CATEG_POS       
2   B           CATEG_NEG       
3   C           CATEG_POS       
4   D           CATEG_NEG   D           -23
5   E           CATEG_NEG   E           -40
```

For further details, please see: [Visual representation of SQL Joins](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

For subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA AS a LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT FIELD1, "CATEG_NEG" AS CATEG
FROM TableB 
WHERE FIELD2<0        
)  AS b ON a.FIELD1 = b.FIELD1;
```

Result is the same as above. As you can see, i removed the second part of `join` statement, because it's enough to get proper result.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think MS Access supports the `AND b.Field2<0` component. In a previous version of the question I think the OP mentioned that.

Comment: @seanb, MS Access supports it. Check it out.

Comment: I tried running `SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM TableA AS a LEFT JOIN TableB AS b ON a.Field1 = b.Field1 AND b.Field2<0;` it in Access and it errors as 'JOIN expression not supported' and highlights the b.Field2<0. If i delete the `and b.Field2<0` it runs.

Comment: and... ironically.. `SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM (SELECT 0 AS zeroval, TableA.*, * FROM TableA)  AS a LEFT JOIN TableB AS b ON (a.Field1 = b.Field1) AND (b.Field2<a.zeroval);` worked.

Comment: @seanb, what version of MS Access do you have? Try to add brackets around `(a.Field1 .... b.Field2<0)`. Sometimes MS Access behaves strangely, so we have to use tricks to workaround issues.

Comment: Office 365 (sorry, Microsoft 365) Version 2009 Build 13231.20262. Tried bracketing and got this to work: `SELECT a.*, b.* FROM TableA AS a LEFT JOIN TableB AS b ON ((a.Field1 = b.Field1) and (b.Field2 < 0));` Note in my one that 'worked', either I typoed or Access added an extra * in the Table A component, but removing it seems to make it fail. I'm confused at that too. But if the b.Field2<0 works, use that.

Comment: @MaciejLos thanks, I didn't know it was a matter of bracketing. Anyway in my actual code I cannot solve it like this. Suppose you don't have column FIELD2 in TableB and want to left join records from TableA to TableB only when field CATEG in TableA is equal to CATEG_NEG. How can you do it? Plus, you're not answering to why the second query doesn't perform a left join.